# Angular IO - Why interceptor property doesn't change when I modify it with a method?

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-http-interceptors

I have an interceptor in my Angular application to set the Authorization header in my HTTP requests.
I need to set different tokens during the app lifecycle, because some requests are made using a general token, others, relative to the user's account, are made with user's token.

I've set my interceptor like this:

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

/**
 * Interceptor that set the Authorization header
 */
@Injectable()
export class HeaderAuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    private useGeneralToken: boolean;
    private tempToken: string;

    constructor() {
        this.useGeneralToken = true;
        this.tempToken = "";
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (this.useGeneralToken) {
            const authReq = req.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + environment.bearerToken
                }
            });
            return next.handle(authReq);
        } else {
            const authReq = req.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.tempToken
                }
            });
            return next.handle(authReq);
        }
    }

    setTokenToUse(token: string) {
        this.useGeneralToken = false;
        this.tempToken = token;
        console.log(this.tempToken);
    }
}
```

and in my component's controller I use the setTokenToUse method.
I can't understand why, even if logs correctly that the token is changed, the interceptor always use the general token.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: can you explain in your question how your interceptor is provided, an example of route config where is it used and how do you call the setTokenToUse in your component + the calls that should use the new token? It's hard to help you without those information

Comment: Maybe it's not the same instance that is used?